# Cannot swipe back to last screen only works when my finger start swiping on the left first position

Tags: react-native, expo

why I can not swipe back on iOS where my finger is in any position ? I can only swipe back while my finger is on the left position look at the video

I have linked an expo but this expo is only an example , its not work in any other projects

Video:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/101994056/202579150-e54704e5-bf5a-4418-a8da-2d4ad707c9c2.mp4